# How do I group the values from the same day in mulitple years?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

[Dataframe with Day of Year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBsap.png)

I have a dataframe where the index is date. It has two columns. I want to find a way to group those data by the day of the year across all the years and then get a max and min value. To solve this problem I created a DOY column which reliably gives me the day of the year for each year.

I solved this problem by grouping on that DOY column but I hope there is a much simpler way to achieve the same effect using a pandas function. Please let me know if there is!

```
> TMAXDEC   TMINDEC DOY
Date            
2005-01-01  60.08   21.92   1
2005-01-02  57.02   21.92   2
2005-01-03  55.94   32.00   3
2005-01-04  39.02   24.98   4
2005-01-05  37.94   15.08   5
... ... ... ...
2014-12-27  51.98   26.96   361
2014-12-28  55.94   21.20   362
2014-12-29  48.02   12.20   363
2014-12-30  37.94   12.02   364
2014-12-31  26.96   7.16    365
3650 rows × 3 columns
```

Comment: FWIW, day-of-year will mismatch days in leap years like this year. Feb 29th will be the same DOY as March 1 the rest of the years, March 1 will map to March 2, and so on down the line to Dec 31, which as day 366 won't map to anything other than Dec 31 in other leap years. You might want to group by the date explicitly, maybe `month*100+day` or something. Then the leap day itself would be the only one that mapped weird.